# how to display the image on the full background for a perticular div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

how do i display the image on the .middle div to the full screen, i get a little white space at the end of the image in the right.i am using bootstrap 3 and css and html The image in the middle div is not taking the entire space it happens when i use the row class.I have included the css and html code.

```css
#content{
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 25%;


}


.middle {
 background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1415369629372-26f2fe60c467);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 height: 700px;
 font-family:Lato;
 color: white;
}


html{
 height: 100%;
}

h1{
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 5em;
}
hr{
 width: 400px;
 border-top:1px solid #f8f8f8;
 border-bottom: :1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
}
a{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Purfect match</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/all.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  
       <div class="container">
         <div class="navbar-header">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed " data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span> Purfect Match </a>
         </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li> 
           <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Pets For You</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li> 
           <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li> 
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
           <li><a href="#">Sign in <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i></a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Log in <i class="fas fa-user"></i></a></li>
           
          </ul>
        </div> 
      </div>
     
 </nav> 

<div class="middle">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12"> 
                  <div id="content">
                    <h1>Perffect match</h1>
                      <h3>The Only Human-feline dating app</h3>
                      <hr>
                      <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-paw"></i> Get Started</button>
                   </div>
         </div>

  </div>

 </div> 
</div>
<div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-4"> 
                  
                      <a>About</a>
                      <a>Contact</a>
                      
                      <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-paw"></i> Get Started</button>
                   
         </div>
               <div class="col-lg-4"> 
                  
                      <a>Services</a>
                      <a>conformation</a>
                      
                      <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-paw"></i> Get Started</button>
                   
         </div>

  </div>










<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue doens't come from your background-image, but from your last `<div class="row">`

You MUST put the bootstrap `row` inside an element with class `container` or `container-fluid`

Try to replace your last block with :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4"> 

                     <a>About</a>
                     <a>Contact</a>

                     <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-paw"></i> Get Started</button>

        </div>
              <div class="col-lg-4"> 

                     <a>Services</a>
                     <a>conformation</a>

                     <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><i class="fas fa-paw"></i> Get Started</button>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```